# OS X - 10.10.4 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: osx-yosemite, ns2, xcode6.4

I am installing NS2 2.35 in my macbook having OS X 10.10.4. The Xcode which i have install is Xcode 6.4. While installing I am getting following error:

ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [octlsh] Error 1

octl-1.14 make failed! Exiting...

From the following link I have downloaded NS2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view

Following steps I have use to install NS2:

1. Install Xcode
2. Unzip or untar ns-2.35 using the command "tar zxvf ns-allinone-2.35-xxx.tar.gz" (without quotes)
3. The ns-2.35 configuration files contains  the path to xlibdir and  xincdir, so you need not include the path for those directories.
4. kindly ensure that the path to xlibdir and xincdir are installed on your Mac OS(Xcode)
5. execute the command ./install inside the directory (~ns-allinone-2.35-xxx/) (use terminal to install) .
6. Once installed successfully, the path setting information will be  provided to you. copy those informations and put it in a file called  .profile or .bash_profile (please note that there is a dot in these  files)
7. finally execute the command "source .profile" (wihtout quotes) and logout and login back.

After step 5 i.e. ./install i got above mentioned error.

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

---

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

The version you got is my "Oct 2014 update" ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz, for gcc/g++ versions 4.6 .. 5.2 . Not **clang**, AFAIK.

Path´s : # `cd ns-2.35/ && make install` ; `cd ../nam-1.15/ && make install`

---

P.S. : There's a patch for OS X 10 → http://myns2work.blogspot.dk/2013/08/installing-ns-235-on-mountain-lion-and.html

Ref. Google, ns-allinone-2.35 with OS X 10 https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns-allinone-2.35+with+OS+X+10

---